# Uglify and Concatenate scripts from Jade file

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I know that solutions exist that will concatenate a predefined set of scripts in node.js.  However, are there any solutions tailored to Jade that will automatically concatenate the scripts referenced from the template and modify the resulting HTML accordingly?

If not, does Jade expose anything to allow me to do so?  Can I traverse the dom tree post-process and before the content is written to the client?

Comment: Do you mean compiling the template itself or do you actually mean the files included in as `script` in a template? The former can be done with jade itself, the latter no. The latter is usually solved with tools like requirejs. It does concatenating and uglifying of scriptfiles using r.js and allows you to include just one script in your html.

Comment: Clarified question.  Does that mean I cannot traverse the generated dom?

Comment: With require.js the generated dom contains only a single `script` tag. You could traverse the DOM, but you wouldn't see a list of needed scripts. On the other hand, requirejs' main script contains a list of required modules. Take a look [here](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs).